# How to push website from development to production?

Tags: git, deployment, web-deployment

I know this question may be shot down so I'll try to phrase it as best I can.  Can someone please explain how you push your website code from development to production if the codebase is saved in Github in development and master branches and you have development, staging, and production tiers?

Let me give an example.  My Django code has two Git branches, dev and master.  I have three servers corresponding to the tiers I just described.  My development server is configured with one set of global packages (e.g. Apache, MySQL) and Python packages (in a virtual environment).  My staging and production servers may have different versions of these packages than development but they both have the same versions as each other so that they're configured identically.  If I want to push my code from development to production, should I push the development branch to staging, test it there, and if all my tests pass, merge the development branch into the master branch and load this master branch on the production server?  Or, alternately, should I just push the development branch to the production server (having tested it on staging) and then go back down to my development server and merge the dev branch into master since I now know it's working OK on production?  I'm really wary about merging my dev branch into my master branch until after I've verified that the development code branch is working in production.

Comment: Your first suggestion results in an untested deployment to Production, which isn't advised.  Both suggestions result in an untested codebase in Master, which isn't advised.  If you *must* use branches (and chances are you don't need to, most people do that just out of assumption/habit) then you'd want to merge *before* testing and deploying.  Otherwise the sequence of steps you're describing is: Develop -> Test -> Modify In Some Way -> Deploy.  That second to last step seems... risky.

Comment: You're suggesting what not to do but not what *to* do.  Are you suggesting that I merge dev into master on my development tier and then check out master on the staging tier and test it there?  And if it passes, push this new master branch to my production tier but if it doesn't then roll back master to the previous commit, fix the problem in the dev branch and then repeat?